# Did Imam Ibn Jarir al Tabari say women can be Imams of prayer?

Tags: salat, women, authenticity, madhhab

Whenever I searched about the issue of the permissibility of a woman leading a prayer, I find that many people cite al Tabari as having given a verdict that women can indeed lead the prayer. But I never found a source for this claim, in his own books or with a chain of narration.

Did Imam al Tabari really say a woman can be the imam of a prayer?

Comment: Ibn Rushd and an-Nawawi have quoted this in bidayat al-Mujtahid and al-Majmo' however a source for their statement needs to be found however seemingly neither at-Tabari nor Abu Tar left such a statement in their books.